# good way to handle multicast group members

Tags: c, multicast

I am trying to find a good way to handle multicast group members.Keep track when someone joins/leaves the group. Language is C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are implementing an IP multicast router you should add a subscription management protocol above multicast in the application layer.